# AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an error when building my code on an Android device.

When I click button start to get the coordinate, the coordinate is shown on the monitor, but my application was stopped and does not send data coordinate on my server.

The error report from Android Studio:

```
--------- beginning of crash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
  Process: id.codefun.gps, PID: 2418
  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast
to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
      at id.codefun.gps.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:41)
      at id.codefun.gps.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:19)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)  I/Choreographer: Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too
much work on its main thread. Application terminated.
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest; import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context; import android.content.Intent; import
android.content.IntentFilter; import
android.content.pm.PackageManager; import android.os.Build; import
android.support.annotation.NonNull; import
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat; import
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import
android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn_start, btn_stop;
    private TextView textView;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    String dataf;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(broadcastReceiver == null){
            broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    textView.append("\n" +intent.getExtras().get("coodinates"));

                    dataf = intent.getExtras().get("coodinates").toString();
                    System.out.println(dataf);
                    String method = "dataKirim";
                    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
                    backgroundTask.execute(method,dataf);
                    finish();
                }
            };
        }
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("location_update"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(broadcastReceiver != null){
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn_stop  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        textView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if(!runtime_permissions())
            enable_buttons();
    }

    private void enable_buttons() {
        btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),gps.class);
                startService(i);
            }
        });
        btn_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),gps.class);
                stopService(i);
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean runtime_permissions(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},100);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode==100){
            if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                enable_buttons();
            }else{
                runtime_permissions();
            }
        }
    } }
```

gps.java

```
import android.app.Service; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.location.Location; 
import android.location.LocationListener; 
import android.location.LocationManager; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.os.IBinder; 
import android.provider.Settings; 
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public class gps extends Service {

    private LocationListener listener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
                Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
                i.putExtra("coodinates",location.getLongitude()+"-"+location.getLatitude()+"-");
                sendBroadcast(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //noinspection MissingPermission
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,0,listener);

    }
}
```

BackgroundTask.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver; import
android.content.Context; import android.os.AsyncTask; import
android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedWriter; import java.io.IOException; import
java.io.InputStream; import java.io.OutputStream; import
java.io.OutputStreamWriter; import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL; import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import static android.widget.Toast.makeText;


public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    BroadcastReceiver ctx;
    BackgroundTask(BroadcastReceiver ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String post_url = "http://codefun.id/jajal_query_mysqli.php";
        String method = params[0];
        System.out.println(method);
        System.out.println(params[1]);
        if(method.equals("dataKirim")){
            String datag = params[1];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(post_url);
                HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
                String Data = URLEncoder.encode("latlon","UTF-8") +"="+ URLEncoder.encode(datag,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(Data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                return "kirim sukses";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //makeText(ctx, result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that your URL protocol is HTTP and not HTTPS. Try either using a java.net.HttpURLConnection object or a "https://..." URL.

```
 import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
```

replace with

```
 java.net.HttpURLConnection
```

Comment: @Keyumar Thumar : Thank you, now I can send application data to the server, but after the data sent application stops running. 

Why did it happen ?

Comment: @andan add logs so that I can figure out. and accept ans so that it will use full to others.

Thank you. :)

Comment: D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection

Comment: their is not problem with log and its not an error that will not cause application stop for more info - https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html.
You added internet permission in app?

Comment: I have to add in file AndroidManifest.xml. this my source
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="id.codefun.gps">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: yes, you have to add internet permission. as well gps and all other required permission.